# MySQL group by custom month

Tags: mysql

Hi I'm wondering if someone can help point me in the right direction.

I'm aware of how to do a group by clause group by `DATE_FORMAT(r_date, '%Y %m');` when its the standard calendar month, but how do we do a `group by` clause when the clients month runs from the 26th to the 25th of each month.

Comment: Means? Can you provide sample data and expected output?

Comment: Could you provide some examples, like is 2014-05-28 June?.

Comment: Sorry i thought the question was quiet specific,    my client has a custom range for their months i.e. their month starts on the 26th and ends on the 25th so i am unable to group by using the standard method of group by DATE_FORMAT(r_date, '%Y %m') as we would normally in a standard calendar month, how do i group using the custom months or is it not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use DATE_SUB to normalize the month and group by that value:

```
...GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(r_date, INTERVAL 25 DAY), '%Y %m');
```

Comment: I Like the simplicity of your answer, would this cater for their custom month starting on the 26th and ending on the 25th please?

Comment: yes. just try it out. day 26 will be treated as first day of the month (26-25=1) and day 25 will be treated as the last (25-25=30/31)

Comment: you might need to add 1 to month though, since february 26 will be the start of february and february 25 will be the end of january.
if you just need to group them this works for you.